# Android Can not open natvie app from url by customer sheme

Tags: android, intentfilter

i have a ProductDeatailActivity in my android app,now i want to give my users a url,then they can open ProductDeatailActivity by clicking on this link and pass parameters to the activity,but when i entered this link, i can not open my app in the browser,this is my url xgshuo://xgshuo.app/product_detail?product_id=2343535454 i have added the intent_filter

```
<activity android:name=".ui.activity.ProductDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="xgshuo" android:host="xgshuo.app" android:pathPrefix="/product_detail"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: i have tried in chrom browser but not working

Answer (score 0):

you might be looking for this thing http://insidesearch.blogspot.in/2015/11/new-ways-to-find-and-stream-app-content.html

But still its in beta mode so dont try it, it will not work untill google rollout it thought out world.

read this carefully in blog.

> We’re exploring both of these new ways to show you great “app-first”
>   content from a small group of partners, such as HotelTonight, Chimani,
>   Daily Horoscope or New York MTA Subway Map — stay tuned for more as we
>   expand this!

Answer (score 0):

After setting your schema (As shown in your question) to verify your deeplinking code you need to create sample html file using below code and open it in your mobile browser and hit the link  if your application is open then you done right from your side otherwise Issue with browser compatibility.

You can see the reference link : https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test

Here is your test.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <a alt="intent:///product_id=2343535454#Intent;scheme=xgshuo://xgshuo.app/product_detail;package=your_package_name_here;end" href="xgshuo://xgshuo.app/product_detail?product_id=2343535454">android-app://your_package_name_here/xgshuo://xgshuo.app/product_detail?product_id=2343535454</a>
</body>
</html>
```